# Mongoose model data deeper than 1 level

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to design my schema in Mongoose which contains the following collections:

```
Customers
Expenses
Categories
```

Instead of embedding the expenses within the customer, I have decided to create its own collection as a customer could potentially have thousands of expenses.

My first question is, is that the best way to model this? i.e. In the expenses collection, would it be best to have a single document for each expense that has a reference to the customer it belongs to?

My second question is about modeling the expenses.

I want to have something like this (oversimplified it here):

```
{
    "_id": Object,
    "customer_ref": Object,
    "details": {
        "amount": 20.00,
        "description": "An expense"
    },
    "date_created": "April 5th..."
}
```

I have been able to create schema models where the data is one level deep but I'm not sure how you achieve something like the above where I have nested data.

Is mongoose designed to only deal with one level deep data, so I should avoid nesting altogether?

If not how do I achieve something like the above?